# how to enable edge as a backhand for wx.html2.webview in wxPython

Tags: wxpython

I am struggling to follow the instructions in the [WebView docs](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.html2.WebView.html) to enable Edge as the backend. When downloading the [WebView2 SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Web.WebView2) there is no cmake or setup.h to modify and it is not clear how to build it.

Comment: I think they have moved on to wxWidgets/Phoenix on github; which has a [build instructions section in their readme](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix#how-to-build-wxpython-phoenix).

Comment: However, they [don't seem to support Edge](https://github.com/wxWidgets/Phoenix/issues/1724) yet; so I doubt they did in the old version either.